# What is the connection between this hint and the question?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

The picture is a question and its hint, I am not asking for solutions, but how whether a differential equation is linear can help me solve this question?
It's obvious that it is not supposed to be solved in an ordinary way.

Comment: Do you know how to solve the corresponding equations with 0 on the rhs? If so, the procedure is straightforward. Find (by inspection) a particular solution to give you the rhs and then add the general solution. In the case of (b) you use the initial conditions to find the coefficients in the general solution.

Comment: It's obvious that it **is** supposed to be solved in an ordinary way.

Comment: @Kehan Qiu: Did you complete this problem with the given hint? Do any of the answers help you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Hints:**

The homogeneous parts of the solution are nothing but classical and will just require the resolution of two quadratic equations. Then, using the principle of superposition,

a') $x$ is a polynomial of the first degree and it is no big deal to find another polynomial that satisfies the equation.

a") the odd derivatives of the sine are all cosines.

b') $1$ is a polynomial of degree zero and it is no big deal to find another polynomial that satisfies the equation.

b") here you will need both sine and cosine terms. An option is to solve for $e^{ix}$ using complex numbers, then to take the imaginary part of the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert each of the equations into a characteristic equation and then have a general solution in terms of $e$ (and in some cases, $\sin x$ and $\cos x$).

The characteristic equation for (a) is $$c^5 + 4c^3 -5c = 0$$ which can be factored into $$c(c^4+4c^2-5) \rightarrow c(c^2-1)(c^2+5) \rightarrow c(c-1)(c+1)(c^2+5)$$

The characteristic equation for (b) is $$c^3 +2c^2 + c = 0$$ which can be factored into $$c(c^2 + 2c + 1) \rightarrow c(c+1)^2$$

Once you have the general solutions, you can use either undetermined coefficients or variation of parameters to find the particular solution.